# Blue highlight for selected toolbar buttons

Tags: xcode, cocoa

[image: Xcode toolbar]

How can I implement a blue highlight effect for selected/activated toolbar buttons, like in Xcode 5? Is this being done through a new template image format?

Answer (score 2):

OS X and iOS both support "template" images. See:

```
-[NSImage setTemplate:];
```

([**NSImage Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/setTemplate:))

and:

```
-[UIImage imageWithRenderingMode:];
```

([**UIImage Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/imageWithRenderingMode:))

Comment: I am already using template images. The problem is that I don't get the blue highlight. I get the old black highlight effect instead.